# Can I use the middle button on touchpad as right click button?

Tags: mouse, button-remapping

I am using a Lenovo W500 thinkpad. The right click buttons on it have been busted. I was wondering if there was a way to reconfigure mouse functionality to use the center button (primarily for scrolling) as a right clicking button instead.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

[Try xmouse](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to change button functions